# Laravel 7 auth attempt returns false

Tags: php, laravel

I just cant seem to find a solution, my `Auth::attempt()` function always return false and I cant find what I am doing wrong. This is my migration for tblusers:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tblusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('Username')->unique();
        $table->string('FirstName');
        $table->string('LastName');
        $table->string('ContactNo')->unique();
        $table->string('Email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('EmailVerifiedOn')->nullable();
        $table->string('Password');
        $table->integer('AddedBy');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I customized the `User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'tblusers';
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'Password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Therefore the password is no longer visible on `User::` queries, so I use `Auth::attempt` instead. This is how I insert my hashed password:

```
    $password = $request->Password;
    $hash = Hash::make($password);

    $insertData = array(
        ...
        'Email' => $email,
        'Password' => $hash,
        'AddedBy' => 0,
        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
```

This is how I use `Auth::attempt`, can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong as it always returns false.

```
        $credentials = array(
            "Username" => $username,
            "Password" => Hash::make($password)
        );
        
        return dd(Auth::attempt($credentials));
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $response = true;
        } else {
            $response = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'password' field that is passed to `attempt` **MUST** be named `password` (exactly like this). Also you will need to adjust the `getAuthPassword` method on your Model since by default it expects the password field in the database to be 'password'. If this is a new project and database I highly suggest you follow the conventions, but if you want to keep things the way they are, these are the changes you will need to make:

```
$credentials = [
    'Username' => $username,
    'password' => $password,
];
```

Notice the key is `password` and we are not hashing the password, as it is expecting the plain-text version of the password so it can eventually do a hash check on it.

On this Model you will need to override the `getAuthPassword` method:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->Password;
}
```